# Why connecting to SQL Server from Sqoop using Windows Authentication fails?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sqoop

I'm using Sqoop to import data from SQL Server using JDBC-ODBC bridge where the ODBC bridge connects to SQL Server.

sqoop eval works fine.

However sqoop import fails.

Command:

```
sqoop import --query "select * from table where \$CONDITIONS" --connect jdbc:odbc:test --driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager --target-dir /to/hdfs --split-by table_name
```

Error:

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function
>   java.sql.SQLException: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function
>
> at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetStmtOption(JdbcOdbc.java:4423)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.getStmtOption(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:1207)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.getMaxRows(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:641)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.setFetchSize(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:821)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:740)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:759)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:269)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForQuery(SqlManager.java:233)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:304)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>   at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the JDBC driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver from some reason doesn't accept custom fetch size (method setFetchSize()) that Sqoop is issuing when transferring data. Any reason why you're using the JDBC-ODBC bridge and not talking to Microsoft SQL server directly?

You can play with --fetch-size to see if some non-default values will work.